# How to use a Combo Box to select data from different tables depending on the value of another Combo Box

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a simple MS Access database with shows details about complaints received. I have 4 tables which are as follows:

1st Table is called "tbl_Data" which shows generic info like Complaint Detail etc,

2nd Table is called "tbl_Tools" which lists all Tool numbers and descriptions,

3rd Table is called "tbl_Products" which lists all Product numbers and descriptions,

4th Table is called "tbl_Material" which lists all Material numbers and descriptions.

I want to have 2 Combo Boxes in the frm_Complaints which gets the PartNumber from the correct table depending on the data in the 1st Combo Box.

[image: screenshot1]

For example: The 1st Combo Box will list "Tool", "Product", and "Material" depending on what the complaint refers to, and if I select "Tool", the 2nd Combo Box will lookup "PartNo" in "tbl_Tools" only. I have tried Union Queries to merge all 3 tables, but then the data cannot be edited. Is there a simple way in VBA to make the 2nd Combo Box only lookup Part Numbers from the correct table, and then have a 3rd field which shows the corresponding description? 
See screenshot link:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Please format your question into multiple paragraphs, provide example data, any relevant code on the combo boxes (row source, etc.) and example output. In your current format, it's hard to understand and even harder to answer your question.

Comment: You can use `ComboBox_Change` event to get the value of 1st combo box and set the list of 2nd combo box.

Comment: But how exactly do you get the 2nd Combo to select data from the correct table? I can't seem to write the correct Select code, or whatever type of VBA code is required.

Comment: In `ComboBox1_Change` event, get `ComboBox1.Value` or `ComboBox1.ListIndex` to determine which table you want. Then assign the corresponding array to 2nd combo box by `ComboBox2.List`

Answer (score 0):

As my comment, you can set 2nd ComboBox.List trigger by `ComboBox1_Change` event.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Select Case ComboBox1.ListIndex
        Case 0
            ComboBox2.List = ArrayTool
        Case 1
            ComboBox2.List = ArrayProducts
        Case 2
            ComboBox2.List = ArrayMaterial
    End Select
End Sub
```

Or something like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "Tool"
            ComboBox2.List = ArrayTool
        Case "Products"
            ComboBox2.List = ArrayProducts
        Case "Material"
            ComboBox2.List = ArrayMaterial
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks promising, but what do I do with ArrayTool? How does ComboBox2 look up the 2nd field of tbl_Tools to show the list of tool part numbers?

Comment: The ArrayTool is the list of tool part numbers like you said. You have to build it yourself since I don't know anything about your table data.

Comment: But if i have a very long list of Tool numbers (approx 40,000 numbers), is using an Array feasible? Can I not just link directly to [tbl_Tools].[PartNo]

Comment: Why not just give it a try? You can assign the list by `Range.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely change the table you select using the method outlined above
- not just pick different arrays -use select case in VBA, and put the SQL into VBA, exactly as you would write it in Access, but within speech marks. In the below, the case changes, on the basis of a change in value of a text box (Me.Poltxt)(not a combo box), and this code sits within a longer sub routine that is triggered by the update of a combo box not mentioned here - but the principle is just the same.
Elements 1 and Elements 2 are the 2 different tables.

```
Select Case Me.Poltxt.Value

Case "Pol1"
Me.Polcbo.RowSource = "SELECT [Elements 1].[ElemName] FROM [Elements 
1] ORDER BY [Elements 1].[ElemName];"


Case "Pol2"
Me.Polcbo.RowSource = "SELECT [Elements 2].[ElemName] FROM [Elements 2] ORDER 
BY [Elements 2].[ElemName];"                     

Case Else: Me.Polcbo.Value = "N/A"

End Select
```